# return only exact match with grep

Tags: awk, grep

All I want is the return value from the exact match of one specific line.

For example `/sbin/megacli -LDInfo -Lall -aALL -NoLog | grep "Virtual Drive:"`
returns
`Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)`

The normal output is like

```
Adapter 0 -- Virtual Drive Information:
Virtual Drive: 0 (Target Id: 0)
Name                :
RAID Level          : Primary-5, Secondary-0, RAID Level Qualifier-3
Size                : 3.271 TB
Sector Size         : 512
Is VD emulated      : No
Parity Size         : 558.406 GB
State               : Optimal
```

I am only interested in that Virtual Drive number, because I iterate over it. Is there some mode like -A where the next line returns, but only the next character?
My desired output is just `0` in this example.

I tried some regexes but on match, the whole line (and other unrelated) was returned. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead of [grep](/questions/tagged/grep):

```
megacli .... | awk '/^Virtual Drive/ {print $3}'
```

`awk` splits each line (which is in the variable `$0`) on whitespace and populates the variables `$1` and up. `$3` is here the third "word" on the matching line.

Comment: This works, thanks mate :) Can you explain what `$3` does?

Comment: @jank04 Great! I added an explanation